# PHP format table in number format

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I'm quite new to PHP, so forgive me for asking this simple question, but I can't get a simple table formatted properly.

I use PHP to get results from MYSQL and show that in a HTML page. The table has ID-labels left and on top, the body is numerical.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$sql = "CALL pivot('DATA', 'amount', 'scen_id', 'dim2_id', 'where ent_id=''abc1''')";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

echo '<table>';

// printing table header
foreach($row as $name => $value) {
    echo "<th>$name</th>";
}
// printing table rows
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($row as $cell) 
        echo "<td>$cell</td>\n";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo '</table>';
```

This is what I get:

```
scen_id ProdA       ProdB       ProdC       Total
BUD     59903423    66278016    55422083    181603522
FORC    37195845    52753807    41339980    131289632
Total   157331578   185154736   164437401   506923715
```

While this is better than an empty page, the first line with data (containing ACT... etc) is missing. It does show up when I run the query in Mysql. I want everything to align right, and the numbers to be formatted with thousands separators. I understand that you can't use CSS for that.

I tried anything already, like this one:

```
echo "<td>".number_format($cell)."</td>\n";
```

but then the result is this:

```
scen_id ProdA       ProdB       ProdC       Total
        59,903,423  66,278,016  55,422,083  181,603,522
        37,195,845  52,753,807  41,339,980  131,289,632
        157,331,578 185,154,736 164,437,401 506,923,715
```

No more row labels.... And also still not aligned right. And still the first line is missing. I hope somebody can tell me how to get this to work. I suppose it's such a standard task that nobody asks this question. I could not find much on the web.

edit: Okay problem solved, thanks guys! For the sake of completeness: here is my working code;

```
$sql="CALL pivot('DATA', 'amount', 'scen_id', 'dim2_id', 'where ent_id=''abc1''')";
$res=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));

echo '<table>';

$first = true;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   if ($first) {
       foreach(array_keys($row) as $name) {
            echo "<th>$name</th>";
       }
       $first = false;
   }
    echo "<tr>";
        foreach($row as $cell) 
        if (!is_numeric($cell)) 
            {echo "<td>$cell</td>\n";} 
        else 
            {echo "<td>".number_format($cell)."</td>\n";}

    echo "</tr>\n";
}

echo '</table>';

?>
```

and here the CSS code:

```
table tr td, table tr th {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    padding: 0 4px;
}
```

Comment: You fetch a row and then just throw it away, and then enter your while() loop. Once you've `fetch()`ed a row, it's GONE.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the first row is missing is probably because you are calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);` and after that `mysqli_fetch_row($res)` without resetting the iterator.

you can prevent this by putting `mysqli_free_result($result);` in between there.

to not include the row labels I'd recomend checking if the `$cell` variable is a number. You can do this with

```
if (!is_numeric($cell)) {
  continue; // Go to next item in array
}

// Your code
```

As for aligning text right. You can do that with css:

```
table tr td, table tr th {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** As Marc B says. It is better to make one loop instead of two. That way you don't have to call `mysqli_free_result($result);` either.

Comment: Thanks colin. I'll try that and let you  know

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks Colin, that test forr numerality worked great.

Answer (score 1):

You're wasting/throwing away the first row:

```
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);  <---fetch first row

foreach($row as $name => $value) {  <--- spit out column names, throw away row

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) <---fetch/display REMAINING rows
```

A better/working solution would be something more like

```
$res = mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error(...));
$first = true;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc()) {
   if ($first) {
       foreach(array_keys($row) as $name) {
            ... display field names
       }
       $first = false;
   }
   ... display row data as usual...
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick answer. I'm going to try that later today and let you know.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I owe you one. The table looks now exactly as I wanted.

Comment: Works! I would not have found that myself. Also the format is fixed now, and in CSS I added a bit of padding and font magic to let it look really nice.

Answer (score -1):

Make a twig extension that returns a list of the fields you want, that way you can use php to get the fields. After that use twig's attribute function

{{ attribute(object, fields) }} to call the getters on the object

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html

```
{% set temp = entities|first %}
{% set fields = getObjectFields(temp) %}
<tr>
{% for property_title in fields %} 
    <td>{{ property_title }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% for item in entities %}
    <tr>
        {% for field in fields %}
            <td>{{ attribute(item, field) }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This may work for you.

Comment: This has absolutely **NOTHING** to do with twig, and telling OP to install some other software to fix a problem is NOT a solution.

Comment: Thanks Sikar. I'll read about twigs and try your solution too

Comment: Okay I read the linked website. I'll keep it in mind. For now the plain PHP / HTML / CSS solution works great.